# Can you make a HTTP PATCH request from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, http

I am working with an API that requires me to make an HTTP PATCH request as part of the URI, is this possible to do from Javascript, my research is showing that I can only do POST, GET, DELETE, and PUT. Is PATCH allowed?

Thank you,

Comment: Most browsers limit the HTTP Methods to POST/GET, support for others are patchy, for instance IE9 does Delete, I haven't seen it in every browser however. For best results, re-phrase your question about browser support for HTTP Methods.

Comment: Browser limits to POST/GET apply to HTML form submission, not XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean by a "PATCH" request, but it seems to be possible (at least in Firefox 6 and Chromium 12). According to the [Mozilla source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla2.0/source/content/base/src/nsXMLHttpRequest.cpp#1663), there is only a limitation of `TRACE` and `TRACK` requests.

A quick testcase:

```
<!-- test.html -->
<script>
var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("patch", "/");
x.send(null);
</script>
```

Any webserver can be used, but I choose for Python's SimpleHTTPServer module.

```
$ ls
test.html
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
localhost - - [21/Sep/2011 17:32:11] "GET /test.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localhost - - [21/Sep/2011 17:32:11] code 501, message Unsupported method ('patch')
localhost - - [21/Sep/2011 17:32:11] "patch / HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

So, as long as the server supports the method, the request get's passed.

Comment: True. There are a few legacy browsers that may have problems with "extension" methods; Microsoft fixed this either in IE8 or in IE9. In older IEs, you can fall back to the XHR ActiveX object which doesn't have that limitation.

Answer (score -2):

As of some research the `PATCH` method seems to be new (march 2010 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) so if you try to define `PATCH` on an XMLHttpRequest it may work, but only on very latest revisions of modern browsers. Don't have a supported browser list found, yet.

Comment: Not correct. A browser doesn't need to "know" a method in order to support it in XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: @JulianReschke the implementation of XHR (not the activeX flavor) in IE8 doesn't support the PATCH method.